# IN vs = in Where Clauses

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I try to create standardized SQL scripts for use in my SSRS reports. If I wish to have a statement such as:

```
Select * from mytable
```

and use a SQL Variable (SSRS parameter) in the where clause, is there any speed advantage to using this:

Where field = @MyField

VS.

Where field IN (@MyField)

I know the second option supports both multiple selections and single selections while the first supports only single.

Are there any performance hits if I write all my queries with the IN statement for uniformity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no performance hit. The optimizer converts the IN to a series of = operations ORed together.

As a side note, I hope you're not really using SELECT * in your actual queries.

Comment: No of course not. I was just saving time rather than typing Field1, field2 etc.

Comment: Why not SELECT * ?  Or at least in `Room` - Android, it is the way. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For one argument optimizer will change that IN into =, in real execution statement.

As both of this arguments are [Sargeble](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/t_sql_where_p2.aspx)  (Joe Stefanelli thanks for attention); the difference in performance may by found where you have sequence value in in clause, for example `IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)` is slower that `between 1 and 6`, because for the IN the index has to be read for each value in this case 6 time for between only once.

Comment: After some googling i must admit that You have right, on some dev blog it was written that this is also nonsargable. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed you supplied a similar answer to this earlier question. You might want to amend that answer as well.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353084/sql-efficiency-vs-in-vs-like-vs-matches/3353223#3353223

Answer (score 0):

the performance does get slow if you have a large no of item in your IN clause