# What is the different between using "IN" vs using "=" inside a query?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I'd like to understand the best way to **restrict** items in a query. For example Query1 returns a list of ID's based of specific detail filters. I would like Query2 to return only items where Query2.ID is the same as Query1.ID.

Which Query2 **Detail Filter** is better? And why?

- Query2.ID IN ( Query1.ID )
- Query2.ID = Query1.ID

Note: Using an "=" filter requires Query2's **"Cross product allowed"** property to be set to "**Allow**".

Answer (score 0):

`IN` is usually used to compare against a list, while `=` compares to a single value.

Examples:

```sql
... WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

vs.

```sql
... WHERE id = 1
```

Some documentation regarding [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9/functions-subquery.html#AEN16806), which might be useful and similar to the cognos notation.

Comment: I understand that. This is not an SQL question it's a Cognos question. Do you have experience using Cognos?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL efficiency - [=] vs [in] vs [like] vs [matches]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353084/sql-efficiency-vs-in-vs-like-vs-matches)

> it depends on the underlying SQL engine. In MS-SQL, for example (according to the query planner output), IN clauses are converted to =, so there would be no difference

Which is better for you will depend on the specific report request.  `=` is for single values and `IN` is for multiple values.  It's all about the prompts.  If you are hard-coding (so, not using a parameter) a filter that looks for a single value, use `=`.

But that's not really what you're asking...

`Query2.ID = Query1.ID`

You need a join, not a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cognos, consider an inner join as an option

- Removes the need to allow cross join
- Query 1 can be a very small data set
- Avoid row to row comparison

1. In cognos, query explorer, from insertable objects/toolbox, drag JOIN below all of your queries (should create query 3)
2. Next, put Query 1 and Query 2 into the available openings
3. Click the join icon to the right of Query 3
   Define cardinality from Query 1 to Query 2 as a 1.1 to 1.n (to achieve the filter effect).  Click Okay
4. Next, single click on the join (just before Query 3 to get focus to set properties) and set the property for filter type to "In".   Examine the generated SQL